# Could not find artifact org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:pom:0.11.0

Tags: kotlin, maven

I am updating my project and here is the issue I'm encountering:
I've update to Maven 3.9.5, Kotlin 1.9.21 and serialization.version to 1.6.
I tried cleaning, restartind... anything I could find. Yet the extension kotlinx-serialization-runtime:pom:0.11.0 is added and I get the error

```
Could not find artifact org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:pom:0.11.0
```

If anyone has any idea, thank you in advance.

I followed the Kotlinx instructions as you can see bellow.(https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master)

Maven
Ensure the proper version of Kotlin and serialization version:

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.9.21</kotlin.version>
    <serialization.version>1.6.2</serialization.version>
</properties>
```

Add serialization plugin to Kotlin compiler plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>kotlinx-serialization</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-serialization</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Add dependency on serialization runtime library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-serialization-json</artifactId>
    <version>${serialization.version}</version>
</dependency>
```